# Detecting how many file inputs are selected and once it reaches a limit toggle a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, input

I have two file inputs. When they have both have a file selected, I want the `#next2` div to toggle in.

I am unsure what I am doing wrong. Am I getting the length of how many inputs are selected correctly?

Any help is appreciated.

```js
jQuery.fn.fadeBoolToggle = function(bool) {
  return bool ? this.fadeIn(400) : this.fadeOut(400);
}
$(".upload-img[type='file']").change(function () {
         var files = $(this).prop("files");
         $('#next2').fadeBoolToggle($(files).length == 2).addClass('block');
     });
```

```css
#next2 {
  display: none;
}
.block {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" runat="server">
  <input type="file" id="brokerage-logo-input" class="upload-img">
  <input type="file" id="personal-pic-input" class="upload-img">
</form>
<div class="proceed-btn sans-pro" id="next2"><span class="proceed-btn-text">PROCEED</span></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am unsure what I am doing wrong.

You are only checking `.files` property of `this` element, which will be `1` if user selected file,  without `multiple` attribute set. You are not checking `.files` property of each `<input type="file">` element.

You can create an array of `input` elements,  use `Array.prototype.every()` to iterate `.files` property of each `input` element, return `Boolean` evaluation of `.files.length` for both `<input type="file">` elements.

```js
jQuery.fn.fadeBoolToggle = function(bool) {
  return bool ? this.fadeIn(400) : this.fadeOut(400);
}
var inputs = $(".upload-img[type='file']");
inputs.change(function() {
  var bool = Array.prototype.every.call(inputs, function(input) {
               return input.files.length
             });
  $('#next2').fadeBoolToggle(bool).addClass('block');
});
```

```css
#next2 {
  display: none;
}
.block {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" runat="server">
  <input type="file" id="brokerage-logo-input" class="upload-img">
  <input type="file" id="personal-pic-input" class="upload-img">
</form>
<div class="proceed-btn sans-pro" id="next2"><span class="proceed-btn-text">PROCEED</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check that every input has a value inside a $.each

Try to modify your script in this way and work.

```
$(".upload-img[type='file']").change(function () {
    var allSelected = 0;
    var numOfInput = $(".upload-img[type='file']").length;
    $.each($(".upload-img[type='file']"), function(idx, val){
        if($(val).val().length){
            allSelected++;
        };
    })

    $('#next2').fadeBoolToggle(allSelected==numOfInput).addClass('block');

 });
```

Comment: Why check `.val()` and not `.files` property?

Comment: yes... I can use also `val.files.length` instead `$(val).val()`